# VS project Settings is building a .config file with no <appSettings> or <add> elements

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager, settings.settings

I started adding settings to my C# project in VS2010, by adding rows in the Project -> Properties -> Settings tab.  A Settings.settings file (with Settings.Designer.cs file) was automatically generated under Properties.

But when I try to access some settings in the code like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameOfSetting"]` it always returns null; AppSettings.Count is always 0. Furthermore I checked the bin folder and when I build the project, *there is no MyProjectName.exe.config file or app.config file* there.

What might have wrong with the VS project?  How do I force it to create the .exe.config file like it's supposed to?

**UPDATE:**

I completely removed/deleted the app.config and Settings files from my project then re-added one setting in the project properties, to re-create it from scratch. When I built the project again, this time a ProjectName.exe.config file *is* in the \bin folder. But my code gets the same results: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"] is null and AppSettings.Count = 0.

Here is the auto-generated app.config file, in the project folder, which is identical to the Project.exe.config file created in a build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MyDarnProject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <MyDarnProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>21937058</value>
        </setting>
    </MyDarnProject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I notice that the element is named applicationSettings, not appSettings as expected. And the setting itself is totally different, with a  element and  child element, instead of `<add key="MySetting" value="21937058"/>` like in others' examples.  I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2010, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

The Settings.Designer.cs code has everything exactly as in an example given below, except that there's no set to go with the get but I don't think that's a big deal.

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("21937058")]
public long MySetting {
    get {
        return ((long)(this["MySetting"]));
    }
}
```

`MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting` does access the setting value! So I guess I may have to do it that way; I'm going to consider that a *workaround* since I still have no clue why the project isn't building the ProjectName.exe.config file the way every other project I've ever made does.

Comment: Please show a snippet of what your .Config file looks like this would be very helpful also show the .CS Code where you are trying to access the key / value thanks..

Comment: Highlight the file in the solution explorer and check the Build Action in the properties window.

Comment: also the app.config file is normally use for design time the actual .config file that your project reads from would be MyProjectName.exe.Config check a directory where your project is located for the app.config file

Comment: Guessing, these are DLL project settings?  Or settings that have scope = User so they never were assigned yet?

Comment: @HansPassant No it's an .exe console app right now [will be a Windows Service], and I did check that all the settings I've put in are Application scope.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Like I said, the /bin folder after I build the project has **neither** an app.config nor a MyProjectName.exe.config file -- VS simply isn't building/compiling/creating a .config that's accessible to the .exe  In the project folder, there is an app.config that VS auto-generated at the same time it generated Settings.settings and Settings.Designer.cs in project/Properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it from this property:

```
YourAppNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.NameOfSetting
```

You can easily see how to reference the values if you take a closer look at the `Settings.Designer.cs` file:

```
namespace YourAppNamespace.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("asas")]
        public string NameOfSetting {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["NameOfSetting"]));
            }
            set {
                this["NameOfSetting"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameOfSetting"]
```

Will look for `<appSettings>` section in `App.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NameOfSetting" value="Foo"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To access settings in `Settings.settings` file use (Visual Studio will help you resolve namespace of `Settings` class- that is one in `Properties` folder of your project). `Settings` class will have strongly-typed properties for all rows that you have added to Project -> Properties -> Settings tab:

```
var value = Settings.Default.NameOfSetting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a  section in your **App.config** file

here is an example you can follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="somesetting" value="7"/>
    <add key="somelocation"  value="abc.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

you read the above using code shown below

string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["somesetting"];
string configvalue2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["somelocation"];
```

if you want to access the Properties within the Settings you can do this

```
Properties.Settings.Default.<Your_Setting_Name>
```